# Como crear una silueta de un PNG en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imagen

Tengo problemas para poder crear una silueta de un PNG. He añadido una imagen para que podáis entender mejor lo que digo. Por ejemplo tengo el PNG a color como en el dibujo a color, y me gustaría crearle una silueta completamente en negro.

La imagen se encuentra en un `ImageView`:

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

¿Que pasos debo seguir?, Gracias de Antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿De donde obtienes la imagen, /raw , /assets o es un  recurso? o ¿la imagen se encuentra en un ImageView?, Agrega más información por favor, recuerda agregar lo que hayas intentado o investigado,saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder, seria un ImageView.

Comment: Lo que deseas es reemplazar la imagen de tu ImageView por la "silueta"  ?@Fumatamax

Comment: Bueno lo que quiero es sacar la silueta en negro tal cual como se ve, he visto que se puede hacer con esto setColorFilter(), pero esta deprecated.

Comment: Exacto pero setColorFilter() no es obsoleto, agrego una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que deseas es sencillo, si tienes la imagen definida en tu ImageView, obten la referencia:

```
ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Define una Matriz de colores definiendo una saturación de 0:

```
 ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
 matrix.setSaturation(0);
```

y aplica a tu `ImageView` el filtro con esta matriz:

```
 ColorMatrixColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
 imageview.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
```

de esta forma obtendrás una versión de la imagen en blanco y negro la cual similar a una silueta.